# Auto-Mount NTFS drive via fstab - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab, automount, nemo

I have modified `fstab` to auto-mount my secondary hard drive to a custom location and assign owner and group on Ubuntu 18.04. I am facing some issues and I know that probably the problem is on mount parameters, but I am not sure how exactly. The issues are:

1 - I can't change permissions on files:
[image]

2 - I can't attach files that are located in this drive to e-mails via any browser:
[image]

Also, I am using `nemo` as file manager. As for the second issue, I am not sure if the issue is on `nemo` or on mount parameters as well. To install `nemo` I used the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller

xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search      # set as the default manager
xdg-mime query default inode/directory                                              # check the default manager
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false                 # Disable default desktop handling
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true                              # Make sure Nemo is set to handle desktop
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences start-with-dual-pane true
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I am missing the permissions of `/media/DATA`  in your question. And please stop using chmod 777. it is -never- the correct command. And pretty useless on windows based partitions. You set the owner and group during MOUNTING. Not on files or dirs,

Comment: The mount permissions are: `ls -l /media/
drwxr-xr-x  1 ioaniatr moderators 4096 Jan  6 00:13 DATA
` because I am using `umask=0022`.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: I did, but still I don't know what is wrong with my settings. I even tried 'try and error' technique!

Comment: Before doing any other trouble shooting, make sure the ntfs partition is in a consistent state before you mount it in linux. Use the file checking tools in MS Windows and fully disconnect the drive there, or fully shut down WIndows (no hibernate, no fast start). Check only whether problems persist once you are sure the volume is clean.

Comment: I already checked this (no hibernate, no fast start). If not fully disconnected, I can't even edit the files (read only mode).

Comment: Just noticed, chromioum doesn't pop-up nemo, but Nautilus when is about to attach files. Am I missing something? command: `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`  output:
`nemo.desktop`